# Cython, pure Python mode: .pxd and @locals

Tags: python, cython

I have a Python program that I want to speed up using Cython, while keeping the source readable by the Python interpreter ("Pure Python mode"). I get a 20% speed increase just by compiling it as it is. Then I created a .pxd file and tried to add some "@cython.locals(...)" throughout my .pyx script to fix the types of variables. But I see no difference in running time before and after the addition of these two features.
So I have three similar questions:

First, I added in my .pyx :

```
@cython.locals(start=cython.int, end=cython.int)
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, start, end)
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
```

Is this even doing anything?

Second, if I have in my .pyx a class

```
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 0
    def __call__(self, x):
        self.n += 1
```

is there anything I can do to fix the type of "n" (as would a "cdef int n" after the "cdef class")?

Finally, if I have in my .pyx a function :

```
def count():
    <do something with variables a,b,c>
```

does it change anything to write the following in the .pxd? :

```
cpdef inline count():
    cdef:
        int a
        int b
        int c
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got help from Cython's official forum at Google Groups. If one writes a .pyx file, the .pxd is only to share function definitions with other modules; in particular, it will not enhance the original functions and all three examples above add nothing from compiling the raw python script.

One can use a .pxd in conjunction with a raw .py though, to fix variable types of simple functions and class attributes, but it has many limitations.

@cython.locals does not allow to touch class attributes, but only (non-**xxx**) function arguments. It would do nothing in this particular case. In general I think these decorators are not the correct approach.

The best way to do is probably to rewrite some of the functions with the Cython syntax in a .pyx, in public mode ("cpdef" creates a Python wrapper), compile it, and then import the function/classes into the Python code as one does with other libraries. But it is not really pure Python anymore.

Comment: Would you please link to the discussion on Google Groups? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

About your `@cython.locals`, I think you should try placing it just before the `__init__` method, not before the class declaration, because it refers to the constructor.

Consider using [`@cython.cclass`](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html#extension-types-and-cdef-functions) for declaring a `cdef` class.

To fix the type of a variable, use `cython.declare()`, or `@cython.locals`, see [magic attributes](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html#magic-attributes).

The options above must be included in the `.py` or `.pyx` file, and are special cython functions and/or decorators.

The alternative is to keep your code in a `.py` file as pure python, and use an augmenting `.pxd` file with the same name. The python code will look cleaner, but it may take longer to maintain the separate `.pxd` file. See [this](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html#augmenting-pxd) section. This is basically what you're doing in your last example.

Comment: I understood that making a `cdef` class makes my class usable on the C side, but since it already compiles as it is, is there an interest in using `@cython.cclass` here? I ran through the official doc a dozen times and really still don't get what I am doing...

Comment: yes, it should run faster. read the page on cdef classes, [link](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html)